# How to split a dictionary based on similarity of values into two separate dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dict`:

```
dictionary =  {'1': 'a',
     '2': 'a',
     '3': 'b',
     '4': 'b'}
```

and I want to split it such that one `dict` contains all items with `value == 'a'` and the other one all items with `value == 'b'`:

```
dict_a = {'1': 'a',
     '2': 'a'}

dict_b = {'3': 'b',
     '4': 'b'}
```

How can I do this in an short way?
My approach

```
dict_a = {}
dict_b = {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
     if value == 'a':
         dict_a = dict(key, value)
     else:
         dict_b = dict(key, value)
```

does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
dict_a={}
dict_b={}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if value == 'a':
        dict_a[key] = value
    else:
        dict_b[key] = value
```

In your original code, you were recreating `dict_a` or `dict_b` every time you went through the loop.

If you're not absolutely sure that your starting dict contains ONLY `"a"` or `"b"` values, use this instead:

```
dict_a={}
dict_b={}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if value == 'a':
        dict_a[key] = value
    elif value == 'b':
        dict_b[key] = value
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `filter()` if you want a shorter solution:

```
dict_a = dict(filter(lambda kv: kv[1] == 'a', dictionary.items()))
dict_b = dict(filter(lambda kv: kv[1] == 'b', dictionary.items()))
```

Note that this could be slower than a manual `for` loop if you have to do it more than once.

In any case, if you already know that every single value in `dict_a` is going to be `"a"` and every single value in `dict_b` is going to be `"b"` this seems like a waste of space, you don't need dictionaries at all:

```
keys_a = []
keys_b = []

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key == 'a':
        keys_a.append(key)
    else:
        keys_b.append(key)
```

Or with `filter()`:

```
keys_a = list(filter(lambda k: dictionary[k] == 'a', dictionary.keys()))
keys_b = list(filter(lambda k: dictionary[k] == 'b', dictionary.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If values in your initial `dict` are not in your control, or not limited to `a` and `b`, you can try following:

```
def combine_similar_values(input_dict):
    output = {}
    distinct_values = set()
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        v_str = str(v)
        if v_str in distinct_values:
            output[v_str][k] = v
        else:
            distinct_values.add(v_str)
            output[v_str] = {k: v}
    return output.values()
```

`combine_similar_values` will return a list of dictionaries where each `dict` contains same values.